# Unequal space between paragraphs and header-footer

Tags: spacing, header-footer, paragraphs

As you can judge from the page below, the vertical space between the text and the header line and the text and the footer line is not equal.....

[image]

This is much more prominent in a PDF reader  so I am trying to get equal space. How do I accomplish this using these settings?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english,openany,oneside]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\makeatletter

\pdfpageheight\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth\paperwidth

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@part}{\gdef\parttitle{#1}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\@spart}{\gdef\parttitle{#1}}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}

\usepackage[nouppercase,headsepline,footsepline,automark]{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\clearscrheadings
\chead{}
\cfoot{}
\ihead{headertext}
\ohead{\parttitle}
\ifoot{\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}\leftmark}
\ofoot{\rule{0pt}{\ht\strutbox+\dp\strutbox}\thepage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{pdfcolmk}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\providecommand{\HUGE}{\Huge}% if not using memoir
\newlength{\drop}% for my convenience

\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\usepackage[includeheadfoot, margin=1.5cm,headsep=25pt,footskip=25pt,a4paper]{geometry}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the native `\areaset` command from Koma-Script instead of the `geometry` package:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english,openany,oneside,headinclude,footinclude]{scrbook}
% Set the typeset area (trim - 2*margin)
\areaset{18cm}{26.7cm}
```

Note by the way that if your book has to be printed, you might also want to add a binding correction to it, which can also be done with `\areaset`, for example, for a 1cm binding correction:

```
\areaset[1cm]{17cm}{26.7cm}
```

The problem might also come from the fact that you're drawing rules in the header/footer manually. The Koma-Script documentation explains how do draw a separator for headers/footers:

```
\setheadsepline{.4pt}
```

and the corresponding for the footer will draw lines *between* the header and the main content, instead of drawing it *inside* the header, so that might just fix your issue.

Comment: I've changed the class settings, removed geometry package and added the \areaset command, but the problem still remains. Instead, the whole page seems to shift up a bit. In case you are unclear, I have updated the image in the question.

Comment: Raphink, is this tested by you?

Comment: It's the settings I use for my own books, and I haven't noticed that problem. That said I don't use lines both up and down, so maybe I have the same issue and I just don't see it. See also my edited answer about not drawing a rule in the header/footer.